# How to change the default EOL to unix on cygwin in vi

Tags: svn, cygwin, vi

I need to manually change the svn log for a project hosted on the web. I am using sliksvn (1.9.5) and cygwin (2.8.0-1) on Win8.1 where vi is really vim 8.0.542. My problem is that I cannot get rid of the DOS EOL character. Specifically,

```
568$ svn log -r31
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r31 | XXX | 2017-05-01 13:34:34 +1000 (Mon, 01 May 2017) | 1 line

Separate style from content
------------------------------------------------------------------------
569$
```

But

```
569$ svn log -r32
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r32 | XXX | 2017-05-24 08:58:20 +1000 (Wed, 24 May 2017) | 2 lines

Check grammar

------------------------------------------------------------------------
570$
```

Note there's an extra blank line caused by the pesky ^M of r32. The way I edit the log is `svn propedit -r 32 --revprop svn:log --editor-cmd 'vi -b'`
which will show me the hidden characters. In vi, I checked with `:set ff` that the temporary `svn-prop.tmp` is unix and saved in unix mode after deleting the \r. But the log still have the extra blank line. How do I get rid of it? Thanks.

Comment: to delete a line in vi uses command `dd`. Usually to convert a file removing the `\r` you should use `d2x`

Comment: Tried but didn't work. I suspect it's not a vi but Cygwin issue